# Out of bounds error at keyword to alpha comparison

Tags: java, string, replace, keyword, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to put keywords into a string buffer alpha and omit duplicate characters. I am getting an out of bounds error at the keyword to alpha comparison.

```
public String putKeyword(String keyword)
{
    StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer();

    alpha.append(keyword.charAt(0));
    for(int i = 1; i < keyword.length(); i++){
        boolean found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            if(keyword.charAt(i) == alpha.charAt(j))
                found = true;
            if(found = false)
                alpha.append(keyword.charAt(i));
        }

    }
    return alphabet = alpha.toString();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you've forgot the tag of the main language here. I'm assuming this is Java.

Comment: I've added it to your question's tags, no need to add it in the title. `;)`

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this situation:

`keyword = "aaaaa"'`

Let's iterate through your algorithm:

```
alpha = "a"
```

Take notice what are the contents of `alpha`

```
i=1, j=0
```

keyword.charAt(1) == alpha.charAt(0)
a == a
alpha = "a"

```
i=2, j=0
```

keyword.charAt(2) == alpha.charAt(0)
a == a
alpha = "a"

```
i=2, j=1
```

Since alpha only has 1 char, exception is thrown because you are trying to access 2nd element.

Solution: use HashSet to keep seen status.

```
public String putKeyword(String keyword) {
    StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer();
    Set<Character> seenChars = new HashSet<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < keyword.length(); i++) {
        char c = keyword.charAt(i);

        if (!seenChars.contains(c)) {
            seenChars.add(c);
            alpha.append(c);
        }
    }

    return alpha.toString();
}
```

Comment: This one is a good explanation but can you edit the post. will +1 if you do so.

Comment: Done :) I formatted the text and added a solution using `Set`.

Comment: Then +1 for you in store.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public String putKeyword(String keyword)
{
    StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer();

    alpha.append(keyword.charAt(0));
    for(int i = 1; i < keyword.length(); i++){
        boolean found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < alpha.length(); j++){
            if(keyword.charAt(i) == alpha.charAt(j))
                found = true;
        }
        if(found == false)
            alpha.append(keyword.charAt(i));
    }
    return alphabet = alpha.toString();
}
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: `if(found = false)` can be simplified to `if(!found)`

Comment: Your posted code even will fail to compile cause of `if(found = false)`. Moreover, I don't see any difference between your posted code and OP's posted code.

Comment: @Rahul: missing equal sign added. As to "what's different" - the difference is that the `if(found == false) alpha.append(keyword.charAt(i));` is pulled out of the loop on `j`, so that all characters are checked for duplication before appending to the target StringBuffer.

Comment: @Rahul: having had time to think about this some more, I just realized that the comparison on the `j` loop was the problem. All this notwithstanding, though, I like the solution proposed by @Lopina better and have upvoted it. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful that array indexing begins at zero, but your first for-loop starts looking at 1 while the second starts at 0.  It doesn't look like that is the intention of the loop.

Comment: I believe that part of OP's code is correct. If you'll notice, the element at keyword(0) is first added to the target StringBuffer (`alpha.append(keyword.charAt(0));`) - then the code loops `i` starting at 1, because the 0th element has already been copied.